# How do I set a default binding property for a parent object property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, attributes, razor

I'm running into a ton of something that looks like this:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    public string Property2 {get;set;}
    public AddressType Type {get;set;}
    [RequiredIf("", "", ErrorMessage="...")]
    public int TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return Type.Id;
        }
        set
        {
            Type = new AddressType() { Id = value };
        }
    }
}

public class AddressType
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

so that I can model bind the info in a razor form and get binding back and forth.  I'm wondering if there is anything out there that anyone knows where I can either apply an attribute against "AddressType" to set the default binding property for the class, or put an attribute against the 'Type' field of TestClass and say "When you bind, really bind to Type.Id, but validate against the whole object otherwise...

Not sure if I'm asking this right, but I just want a cleaner implementation if at all possible... I feel like adding the TypeId is unnecessary cruft in the class, and it makes it difficult to read.

Thx Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm not 100% across what you are asking here but I'll give it a go by assuming AddressType is nullable.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public AddressType? Type {get;set;}
    public int TypeId
    {
        get
        {
            return Type.HasValue ? Type.Value.Id : 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at AddressType though I'm guessing that its a lookup type sourced from a datastore of some kind. I use T4 templates to generate these kinds of lookup lists (that don't change values between releases) as enums in my apps. Which if you do it will relieve you of a bunch of stress.

Now if what you want is a dropdownlist of AddressType values in your razor view you're going to have to do a little big of work in the controller (Not much thankfully)

```
public class BetterTestClass
{
    public AddressType? Type {get;set;}
}
```

...In your AddressController

```
public ActionResult Create(){

    // the name in the ViewBag should match 
    // the property you want to have a list on 
    ViewBag.Type = repository
                   .AddressTypes
                   .ToList()
                   .Select(p => new SelectListItem { 
                                    Key = p.Id, 
                                    Value = p.Description});

    ViewData.Model = new BetterTestClass();
    return View();
}
```

There are plenty of examples around if you search for @Html.DropDownList

**EDIT**

It's really difficult to work out what you are trying to achieve by your question. But I'll try and help. First do I understand your question correctly:

- TestClass has a 0..1 relationship with AddressType
- Address Type has an Id because it is an Entity class
- For some reason you want the Id of AddressType to be set via the UI when AddressType is set. (which I outlined in my answer the inference being that you won't need required attributes)

Comment: How does it map back with validation that I have indeed picked a proper AddressType based on binding on the Id?  Presently we are doing just that, and we still have to expose AddressTypeId against the "TestClass" object so that we can handle the validation as expected.

Comment: have you read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: I believe "Yes"... my drop down list should list out all of my address types, and should be bound in the drop down list by the ID, but I don't want to expose the AddressTypeId in the TestClass... I just want to expose the object property in TestClass that contains "AddresType".